# unable to start android in the emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I've just installed Eclipse with SDK and ADT on windows 7 x64 I've created an emulator and tried to start it with android-8 but the emulator started with a black screen and doesn't any error !?!
what should i do ?

Comment: ? Maybe it's just loading

Comment: So there're could be many reasons which could depend on your particular system. I suggest you to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com). It's faster and very stable.

Comment: I think my emulator freezing because nothing happened for a long time!

Comment: I really think you'll need to add more details. It's not very likely that anyone will be able to figure out the problem based on just this.